# How to loop form/input file with different title

Tags: php, html, forms, loops, foreach

[loop with different title to input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxhNc.png)

Hai!, i was wondering how do I loop this input file with different title. As I underlined with blue color each input file has different title. Safety data sheet , certificate and etc.

this is my current code :

```
$titles = [
    'Sijil',
    'PDF',
];

foreach ($gambar as $value) {

    foreach ($titles as $title) {
        echo $title;
    }
    echo ' <input type="text" value=" ' . $value['els01filename'] . '   " > ';
    echo '<br>';

    ?>

 <?php
}
?>
```

and the output :

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7o4K.png)

i use to foreach inside foreach and the output is not what i wanted.

Comment: you inner loop is only repeating echoing the values 'Sijil' and 'PDF' (iterating over these 2 array elements) to make it `SijilPDF` . So what is your real intention ?

Comment: your echo should be inside the 2nd foreach

Comment: @KenLee i want to make it each input has its own title

example ;-

Sijil
<Input type="file">

Pdf 
<Input type="file">

You may refer to the attachment given. Wanna do similar like that

Answer (score 0):

Please amend your code so that echo statements are inside your the inner loop (except the `<br>` which means new line);

So the code will be like:

```
<?php
$gambar = [
    '1',
    '2'
];


$titles = [
    'Sijil',
    'PDF'
];

foreach ($gambar as $value) {

    foreach ($titles as $title) {
        echo $title;
        echo '<input type="text" value=" ' . 'hello' .  '" > ';
    }
        echo '<br>';
}
?>
```